# C++ code for detecting media inside CD/DVD-rom

Tags: c++, winapi

Helo,

I have been testing a c++ code that detects [insertion/removal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215(v=vs.85).aspx) of CD/DVD plate.
The code i tested worked very well for detecting insertion/removal of CD/DVD.

However i want to extend this code to detect whether there is a plate already inside the CD/DVD tray during startup. Any ideas how i can extend this code to check this during startup? The code i have tested so far is as follows:

```
  char FirstDriveFromMask(ULONG unitmask)
{

char i;
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
    if (unitmask & 0x1)
        break;
    unitmask = unitmask >> 1;
}
//cout << "dd" << (i + 'A');
return(i + 'A');
}




   LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lParam;
    TCHAR szMsg[80];


        switch (wParam)
        {
        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            // Check whether a CD or DVD was inserted into a drive.
            if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
            {
                PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)lpdb;

                //check which letter is the new device
                if (lpdbv->dbcv_flags & DBTF_MEDIA)
                {                       
                    cout << "CD/DVD has been inserted in: " << FirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask) <<" drive"<<endl;
                }
            }
            break;

        case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
            // Check whether a CD or DVD was removed from a drive.
            if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
            {
                PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)lpdb;

                if (lpdbv->dbcv_flags & DBTF_MEDIA)
                {                                   
                    cout << "CD/DVD has been removed from: " << FirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask) << " drive" << endl;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            /*
            Process other WM_DEVICECHANGE notifications for other
            devices or reasons.
            */
            ;
        }


    return 1;
}//WinProc
```

Comment: I assume this need some sort of windows tag or something? this isn't much of a C++ question.

Comment: You just need to query the drive in some way and see if it succeeds or fails. Use `GetVolumeInformation()` for example. Even `GetFileAttributes()` might work.